# How to search an IP in an IP range using PHP?

Tags: php, ip

I have about 1000 IP address. I calculate IP ranges for them using the bellow code:

```
public function ipRange($mainIp, $mask)
{
    $mainIpLong = ip2long($mainIp);
    $maskLong = ip2long($mask);

    $netid = long2ip($mainIpLong & $maskLong);
    $broadcast = long2ip($mainIpLong | ~$maskLong);

    //here I insert $netid and $broadcast to a MySQL table
    //so I have abount 1000 records
}
```

It calculates IP range correctly, for example if I call like this:

```
ipRange('91.99.98.243', '255.255.255.240');
```

Result will be:

```
$netid     -> 91.99.98.240
$broadcast -> 91.99.98.255
```

Now I need to have a search function. It should find the sub-range for the given IP address, so if I call `search('91.99.98.249')`, the search() function should show the record that netid is 91.99.98.240 and broadcast field is 91.99.98.255.

How can I do that?

Comment: find the record means calculate the `$netid` and `$broadcast` for a particular IP?

Comment: No, I have them in database. but how can I connect 91.99.98.249 with this record? I can't use if($ip>$netid && $ip<$broadcast), because IP is not int value, and if I use long value of netid and broadcast their value would be negative in 32-bit OS

Comment: What exactly is your question:  Your statements seem contradictory `My problem is not about fetching the record from database, I want to find the record.` and `the search() function should show the record...`

Comment: I mean that my problem is not about database and query, it is about how to find the range. I want something like     if($ip>$netid && $ip<$broadcast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Note: `_getConnection()` function connects to database.
`ip_address` fields includes: IP, netid and broadcast.

```
public function search($ip)
{
    $ranges = $this->_getConnection()->fetchAll("SELECT netid, broadcast FROM ip_address");

    foreach($ranges as $range) {
        $min = ip2long($range['netid']);
        $max = ip2long($range['broadcast']);

        if(ip2long($ip) > $min && ip2long($ip) < $max) {
            $result = $this->_getConnection()->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM ip_address WHERE netid = ? AND broadcast = ?", array($range['netid'], $range['broadcast']));
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function find($ip){
//get $netid and $bcast from db one by one
//loop through all records
if(ip2long($ip)>=ip2long($netid) && ip2long($ip)<=ip2long($bcast) ){
echo $netid;
echo $bcast;
}

}
```